# rendering xml (reversing pdftohtml)

Tags: html, css, xml

I have a document (shown below), created with `pdftohtml` (linux [package](https://www.xpdfreader.com/about.html)/command). It has enough information to render a page. For example, see the page's `height` & `width` attributes. Also some textboxes with coordinates. I am thinking how should I approach the task of rendering it back to a readable, pdf-like view. Appreciate any pointer.

```xml
<page number="112" position="absolute" top="0" left="0" height="992" width="756">
<text top="78" left="108" width="540" height="21" font="22">This configures networking routes such that you have unique IP addresses assigned</text>
<text top="98" left="108" width="118" height="21" font="22">to every service of </text>
<text top="101" left="226" width="135" height="15" font="25">type: LoadBalancer</text>
<text top="98" left="360" width="4" height="21" font="22">.</text>
<text top="132" left="108" width="127" height="28" font="33"><b>Configuring DNS</b></text>
</page>
```

Comment: https://github.com/WZBSocialScienceCenter/pdf2xml-viewer seems to be a project that aims to render the generated XML file

Answer (score 1):

The whole point is it should be a HTML view.

So for example I print this Page to a PDF (Top) and run the pdftohtml command I get the output (Middle) with lower browser HTML view.

[image]

Now I can print to PDF again, However there are penalties for round tripping PDF some links will work but not other links (like that package one), or some other objects ***NOTE the line starting "Also"*** may need co-ordinate re-adjustments. Most easily after correction you could use a single command line to `Chrome/Edge --headless "Print-to-PDF` in place of my manual reprint.

[image]

Comment: the XML output is different from HTML, and cannot be rendered directly by a browser, so I guess I should just use HTML instead of XML. Thanks a lot anyway